# Elasticsearch Java Rest Client index template composed of two composable index templates

Tags: java, elasticsearch, groovy

I am looking for an equivalent request using the Java Rest Client in Elasticsearch:

```
PUT myhost:9200/_index_template/my_template
{
    "index_patterns": ["my_pattern_*"],
    "template": {
      "settings": {
        "number_of_shards": 1
      }
    },
    "composed_of": ["composable_index_template1", "composable_index_template2"]
}
```

I came up with the following solution using Groovy:

```
    def builder = new groovy.json.JsonBuilder()
    def root = builder {
        index_patterns ["my_pattern_*"]
        template{
            settings{
                number_of_shards 1
            }
        }
        composed_of ["composable_index_template1", "composable_index_template2"]
    }

    PutIndexTemplateRequest request = new PutIndexTemplateRequest("my_template")
    request = request.source(builder.getContent())
```

Unfortunately the request fails at runtime with the following message:

`Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is ElasticsearchParseException[unknown key [composed_of] in the template ]`

Comment: Check this link:https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/master/java-rest-high-put-index-template-v2.html

Comment: @SagarPatel: I thought this would create a `_component_template` instead of an `_index_template`

Comment: Component template Java API is available here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/current/java-rest-high-cluster-put-component-template.html

Comment: Thank you. I see. I got confused with the terminology.

Comment: I have post the answer as same link, Please marked as solution if it is help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/master/java-rest-high-put-index-template-v2.html) link for composable index template:
Below is sample code from link:

```
PutComposableIndexTemplateRequest request = new PutComposableIndexTemplateRequest().name("my-template"); 
ComposableIndexTemplate composableIndexTemplate = new ComposableIndexTemplate(List.of("pattern-1", "log-*"),
    null, null, null, null, null); 
request.indexTemplate(composableIndexTemplate);
assertTrue(client.indices().putIndexTemplate(request, RequestOptions.DEFAULT).isAcknowledged());
```